# Did anyone have a problem with select filter in react admin?

Tags: reactjs

I just met react-admin, I'm doing a test and in the test,
I created a filter

```
  <ReferenceInput label="User" source="userId" reference="users" alwaysOn allowEmpty>
      <SelectInput optionText="name" />
  </ReferenceInput>
```

soon after this error appears

Warning: Cannot update a component (`ReactFinalForm`) while rendering a different component (`SelectInput`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `SelectInput`, follow the stack trace as

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show more of your code - in particular what it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

It's reported in project repository issues, including codesandbox: [Interacting with list filters throws a React update component error](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4572)